# Handle CheckBox's Checked and Uncheck event in ViewModel Silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, checkbox, viewmodel

I have a function applied on the check and unchecked event of a checkbox in a silverlight datagrid. I have made the function in xaml.cs part. How can i make the same function in ViewModel?

The main problem is I need to access sender in ViewModel.

```
private void HandleChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        var bindingExpression = chk.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
        if (bindingExpression != null)
        {
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a method in your ViewModel (ie MyViewModel.cs):

```
public void DoCheckboxStuff(bool checked)
{
    ...
}
```

and access it from your View (.xaml.cs) :

```
private void HandleChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
    MyViewModel mvm = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;
    mvm.DoCheckboxStuff(chk.IsChecked);
}
```